# Eagle: Make copper pour connect to entire SMD pad

Tags: eaglecad

So I have a design in Eagle with a few SMD components that have pads that should be grounded. I've done a copper pour (draw polygon->name GND->Ratsnest) to create a top ground plane. On some of my components the ground plane connects to the SMD pad, but only by four narrow traces (such as below):

[image]

I would like the entire SMD pad to connect to the ground plane. It's an RF design so grounding is fairly important. Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called "thermals" and they make soldering easier/possible.  You can disable them in the properties window for the polygon.

If grounding is really important you might be better off with vias in the pad connecting it to a ground plane on the next layer down.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a "thermal relief", and it allows the pad to be soldered without raising a substantial portion of the ground plane to soldering temperature. But this is less important if the board will only ever be assembled using reflow, which raises the entire board to soldering temperature all at once anyway.

You can eliminate the relief on a per-polygon basis; just edit its properties.